# On some servers, many external resources (GA, fonts.com fonts, etc.) error out with "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"?

Tags: javascript

On a few servers I've worked with, many (but not all) of my externally loaded resources error out and throw (in Chrome) "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL".

Including jQuery from the googleapis CDN works fine, but loading a fonts.com JavaScript font file and loading the basic Google Analytics code both error out.

Here's the code (also, here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mstauffer/kZRbG/) if it helps):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>fonttest</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://fast.fonts.com/jsapi/dd7c6b7d-1ecb-4ef4-bf65-c4759f97cbe3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>This is a test of the emergency broadcast system.  This is only a test.  If this had been an actual emergency, the tones you just heard would have been followed by official news or instructions.</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

The headers from these files transfer as `text/javascript`.

Finally, when I view the resource within the Web Inspector's Resources tab, I see some non-Roman characters instead of the actual code of those files, so that makes me think there must be some sort of encoding issue. I tried setting the charset to both `utf-8` and `iso-8859-1` in the document head (using `meta charset`) and neither helped.

[image: screenshot of chrome error]

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you using? DevTools had some resource-related issues fixed recently, so updating to version 20 or later might help. Just to clarify: the fiddle doesn't log any errors and shows correct resource contents for me on 20.0.1132.27 (Official Build 140692) beta.

Comment: I'm on 19 (19.0.1084.56). However, I see the same problem in Safari's web inspector (that is, it transfers the file as some non-Roman characters); the only difference is that it doesn't have the error in red.

And yah, the fiddle doesn't show any trouble for me either; that's why I'm sure this is a server-related issue, not just a code problem. 

I hope this helps clarify. Thanks!

Comment: OK, I also tested it in Chrome Canary (21.0.1172.2), and I get the same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I've solved the problem: My primary HTML page (not the included scripts) had, at some point, become encoded as UTF-16. I changed its encoding (not using `meta charset`, but by editing the encoding of the document itself using my code editor) back to the default, *Western (ISO Latin 1)*, which I assume is the same as iso-8859-1.

My best guess is that at some point I pasted something into this file that had UTF-16 encoding, my editor converted the document's encoding to UTF-16, and then the site assumed the external resources it was importing were also UTF-16, which caused it to misinterpret them.

I'll leave this question & answer up in case someone runs into the same problem.